# start cefsharp project in visual studio2010

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I got the error on importing the .sln (project)
The exact problem troubling me is:

seems,cannot load the csproject.Thats the demo programme,like "winform demo",cannot work.

I appreciate any people,I like cef:)
I am now using c#

Comment: What's the exact error message you receive? For which version of CefSharp? Which VS2010 service pack are you on? It ran last time I checked with VS2010 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are trying to compile from source since you mention "WinForms demo" (it's real name is CefSharp.WinForms.Example).

[This answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a4dc2880-32c5-4426-bb01-cfa71c46526a/the-project-file-cannot-be-loaded-visual-studio-2010?forum=tfsversioncontrol#6d32466d-dd4e-4d30-adf1-d7d12f92af7b) on the MSDN forum gives a few ideas you should check. The most important is:

- Check that you have at least NuGet version 2.7 installed in Visual Studio (the WinForms Example project has a reference to a `.targets` file in a package that NuGet should download, we built it to depend on at least NuGet 2.7)
- Please look in the console for the exact error message and report it here

Also the CefSharp wiki has a Building CefSharp page that might help.